# Generate Word document from PHP

Tags: php, laravel, web-applications, ms-word

I'm looking for a clean way to generate a Word document from my PHP project. I want to make a Web application with Laravel and I'm trying to print out (or better said: generate) a Word document with the data in my database.

Is there a Laravel extension or a supportive way how to execute this in a clean way?

Comment: PHPWord. https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord

Comment: https://github.com/guiguidoc/laravel-phpword